Depicter Slide Display Issue: Images Not Showing Up, Need Assistance
I'm facing an issue with Depicter while trying to display a slide. Everything seems to be working fine except for the images, which aren't showing up. I've checked my code, but I can't seem to pinpoint the problem. Can anyone offer insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!


In my experience, make sure you have an active SSL certificate on the site. I can see you're using the Elementor page builder, so after installing and activating your SSL, go to Elementor -> Tools. In the General tab, click on "Regenerate files". Then go to the "Replace URL" tab, copy and paste the non-ssl version of your URL i.e; starting with "http" in the "old field" and then the SSL version of your URL i.e; starting with "https" in the "new field", click on replace URL button to changes get effected, you might see some number of rows affected. You can check back in depicter to see if images are loading correctly. Depicter seems to be quite strict with SSL and mixed content issues. Hope it helps.

I would recommend to use Inspect Element of browser to get more information. Like sometime there is an issue with the File path or in console if there are some JS issue.
Normally, you have to do settings for the plugins. More suggestions can be provided but only if there is a way to look into the site setting.
